# Is it possible to memorize the sound of a certain pitch?

Tags: memory

Those how have an absolute pitch can name the note when they hear it. For those who don't have this ability is it possible to remember a pitch of at least one note?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it seems like this ability can be acquired with practice.

In [Identifying Notes without Perfect Pitch](http://www.paulheinz.com/paul-heinz-blog/2019/12/17/identifying-notes-without-perfect-pitch), the author picked twelve familiar songs, each of which started on one of the twelve pitches of the chromatic scale. Once he memorized the song-pitch association, he was able to recognize 10 out of of 12 pitches.

Some users of [Music Stack Exchange](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/4061/able-to-recall-music-in-its-correct-key-but-dont-have-perfect-pitch-what-is) mention similar results. For example, one person says they can remember the pitch of their tuning fork, and another suggests the song approach: "If hearing a note instantly reminds you of a song, then I think you *are* identifying that note, just by the song name, not the note name (that you may or may not happen to know)."